# Node-canvas was built without jpeg support (M1 Max, Apple silicon)

Tags: homebrew, nvm, zshrc, apple-silicon, node-canvas

having issues with node-canvas on the **M1 Max apple silicon** machine.
This problem doesn't acquire un intel based machines.

Throwing error: `node-canvas was built without JPEG support`.
Also, necessary packages are installed: `arch -arm64 brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg`

**Environment:**

- Node: **v16.15.0**
- NPM: **8.11.0**
- Homebrew: **3.4.11**
- NVM: **0.39.1**
- Operating system: **macOS v12.4**

```
––Terminal:

...node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:91 SetSource.call(img, src);
Error: node-canvas was built without JPEG support
at setSource (/Users/USERNAME/PROJECT_NAME/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:91:13)
```

```
––package.json

...
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "npm-check-updates": "^13.1.1"
  },
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/cognitiveservices-computervision": "^8.2.0",
    "@azure/ms-rest-azure-js": "^2.1.0",
    "color-convert": "^2.0.1",
    "color-thief-node": "^1.0.4",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.1",
    "helmet": "^5.1.0",
    "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nearest-color": "^0.4.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  },
...
```

```
––.zshrc:

local brew_path="/opt/homebrew/bin"
local brew_opt_path="/opt/homebrew/opt"
local nvm_path="$HOME/.nvm"

export PATH="${brew_path}:${PATH}"
export NVM_DIR="${nvm_path}"


[ -s "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "${brew_opt_path}/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completionexport PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg-turbo/bin:$PATH"

# heroku autocomplete setup
HEROKU_AC_ZSH_SETUP_PATH=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/heroku/autocomplete/zsh_setup && test -f $HEROKU_AC_ZSH_SETUP_PATH && source $HEROKU_AC_ZSH_SETUP_PATH;
# heroku autocomplete setup
HEROKU_AC_ZSH_SETUP_PATH=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/heroku/autocomplete/zsh_setup && test -f $HEROKU_AC_ZSH_SETUP_PATH && source $HEROKU_AC_ZSH_SETUP_PATH;
```